# Mapping the processes to sockets excluding the first core using MPI and SRUN

Tags: mpi, cluster-computing, distributed-computing, slurm, hpc

I'm trying to execute a parallel code with two processes in one node on a 48 core machine with two sockets (1 process per socket). Each process must only use 23 cores of Socket. Process 0 must go from core 1 to core 23 (Socket 0), and Process 1 from core 25 to core 47 (Socket 1). I would like to know how I can exclude the processes from using the first core in each socket (Core 0 in Socket 0 and Core 24 in Socket 1) using SRUN.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `map_cpu` option provided by `srun`. Use it in the flag `--cpu_bind`.

From the [srun manual](https://slurm.schedmd.com/srun.html):

> map_cpu:
> Bind by setting CPU masks on tasks (or ranks) as specified where  is <cpu_id_for_task_0>,<cpu_id_for_task_1>,... CPU IDs are
> interpreted as decimal values unless they are preceded with '0x' in
> which case they interpreted as hexadecimal values. If the number of
> tasks (or ranks) exceeds the number of elements in this list, elements
> in the list will be reused as needed starting from the beginning of
> the list. To simplify support for large task counts, the lists may
> follow a map with an asterisk and repetition count. For example
> "map_cpu:0x0f*4,0xf0*4".

Something like this could be applied in your case:

```
srun --cpu_bind=map_cpu:1,2...23,25,26...44 binary #replace ... with actual numbers
```

Comment: Hi, I tested the solution. I tried to map like "map_cpu:1,2,3,4,5,6...47" excluding 0 and 24. However, for some reason, it binds process 0 to core 0 and process 1 to core 1, while the other cores remain idle. I was successful using a hexadecimal alternative as follows: "srun --cpu-bind=mask_cpu:0x000000fffffe,0xfffffe000000". 

However, that does not solve this question, as I would like to know how to do the same using the decimal approach.